# How to get values of several form elements and send them to controller with vue.js?

Tags: laravel

I am learning Laravel 5.2 and vue.js,and not familiar with the grammars,the question is:

How to get all of the values of the form elements below and send them to controller with vue.js?
Including text,select,textarea,file input,radios,checkboxes.

PS:
There is a plugin in the html demo,it's function is compressing a selected image. 
lrz.bundle.js,https://github.com/think2011/localResizeIMG

html demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="formGroupExampleInput" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Text</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="exampleSelect1" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Select</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="exampleTextarea" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Textarea</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="exampleInputFile" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">File input</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input id="exampleInputFile" name="photo" type="file" class="form-control-file" value="Upload" accept="image/*">
                preview:
                <img id="preview"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2">Radios</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1"> 1
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2"> 2
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3"> 3
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2">Checkboxes</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> 1
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2"> 2
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3"> 3
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/dist/lrz.bundle.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var $preview = $('#preview');
        $('#exampleInputFile').on('change', function () {
            lrz(this.files[0], {
                width: 800
            }).then(function (rst) {
                $preview.attr('src', rst.base64);
                rst.formData.append('fileLen', rst.fileLen);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've a little bit of uncertainty as to whether or not it's actually a Laravel -> Vue setup you're looking for since you have absolutely no Laravel nor Vue code in your question which is extremely broad, but here's a basic template to get started. I use the following in pretty much every project.

***Laravel***

**Create your route** - routes/web.php:

```
Route::post('/myform', 'FormControntroller@submitForm');
```

**Create your controller and method** - app/http/controllers/FormController.php

```
class FormController extends App\Controllers\Controller {

    public function submitForm()
    {
         var_dump(request->all());
    }
}
```

**Create your entry view** - resources/views/app.blade.php

```
        <html>
            <head>
               <title>Minimal Vue Example</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="app">
                </div>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.1/vue.min.js"></script>
                <script src="/js/main.js"></script
            </body>
        </html>
```

***Vue***

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Resource from 'vue-resource'
import Router from 'vue-router'

import Root from './components/Root.vue'


Vue.use(Router)
Vue.use(Resource)

var router = new Router({
   history: true,
});

router.map({
  '/': {
    component: Root
  },
});

// Start up our app
router.start(Root, '#app');
```

**Create your root component** - resources/views/assets/js/components/Root.vue

```
<template>
 <form v-on:submit.prevent="submitForm">
    <input type="text" v-model="formData.username"/>
    <input type="text" v-model="formData.password"/>
 </form>
</template>
<script>
export default {
   data: function() {
      return {
         formData: {
             username: null,
             password: null
         }
      }
   },

   methods: {
      submitForm: function() {
          this.$http.post('/myform', this.formData).then(function(response) {
               alert('Yay, my form was posted!');
          });
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

At this point you'll need to run webpack on your assets, see the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir) on [Elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir).

Again, you've asked a very broad question without providing much background, but this will get you going.

**Notes:** The above code is working code on Vue 1.X, version 2 is slightly different.

For further help on Vue and Laravel, see the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/frontend#writing-vue-components).